# Which FFmpeg command do I use to passthrough .ts to .MP4?

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, mp4

I have a folder full of .ts files I wanna convert to .mp4 without having to repeat the command for each file.

Same quality, same file name (without the old file type at end of name of course)

Windows 10

Comment: Sound like a job for the shell, not ffmpeg.

Comment: @DanielB how do I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Save the code block below as a .bat file

Edit the following lines so it points to your ffmpeg.exe, your input .ts directory, and your output .mp4 directory

> SET "ffmpeg=C:\my_ffmpeg_dir\ffmpeg"
>
> SET "indir=C:\my_input_ts_dir"
>
> SET "outdir=C:\my_output_mp4_dir"

Also edit the ffmpeg settings as you would like. The below is a straight through conversion.

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
SET "ffmpeg=C:\my_ffmpeg_dir\ffmpeg"
SET "indir=C:\my_input_ts_dir\"
SET "outdir=C:\my_output_mp4_dir\"
for %%f in ("%indir%"*.ts) do (
   SET "infile=%indir%%%~nf.ts"
   SET "outfile=%outdir%%%~nf.mp4"
   "%ffmpeg%" -i "!infile!" "!outfile!"
)
echo Done
```

What the code does is basically run through all the matching *.ts files in the input dir, for each one we run

> ffmpeg -i in/file.ts out/file.mp4